# filtrar resultados de relación entre tablas eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hola tengo la siguiente consulta, relaciono tres tablas
1 donde tengo todos los productos
2 donde tengo los productos por listado de precio (manejo varias listas de precio en la que cada producto tiene distinto precio, descuento etc)
3 donde indico la categoria del producto.

con el siguiente codigo obtengo los productos.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $buscarProductos = FichaProductoServicio::all();
    
    $buscarProductos -> each(function($buscarProductos){
        $buscarProductos->fichaPrecio
        ->whereIn('id_lista_precio','=' , '1');
        $buscarProductos->categorias;
    });
```

con un dd sobre $buscarProductos obtengo lo sgte.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me gustaria poder filtrar solo los productos que su 'id_lista_precio','=' , '1'
como  lo intente en la linea $buscarProductos->fichaPrecio->whereIn('id_lista_precio','=' , '1');

como debería hacerlo?

**Edito** a solicitud expongo las relaciones.
tabla donde estan los productos

```
class FichaProductoServicio extends Model
{
 
protected $table = 'ficha_producto_servicios';


public function fichaPrecio(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductoPrecio','id_producto','id');
}

public function categorias(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Categoria','id','id_categoria');
}
```

tabla donde estan las listas de precio.

```
class ProductoPrecio extends Model
{
protected $table = 'producto_precios';

Public function fichaPrecio(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\FichaProductoServicio','id', 'id_producto');
}
```

Comment: Agregue las relaciones entre tablas, no hago 3 consultas solo 1 y uso los metodos. me gustaria que en esta linea pudiera filtrar solo las listas de precio con id = 1 ----  $buscarProductos->fichaPrecio->whereIn('id_lista_precio','=' , '1');

Comment: Prueba de esta forma y me comentas: *`FichaProductoServicio::with(['fichaPrecio' => function ($query) {
     $query->where('id_lista_precio', 1);
}])->get();`*, por cierto la sintaxis que usas con el método *`whereIn`* no es correcta pues el segundo argumento que espera es un  *array*